# How little information does an answer have to have to be NAA as comment?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, declined-flags

- `arrayName.length` will get you the number of entries.
- Set `Devise::Async.queue = :default`

(sometimes even with a link to docs!)

These kinds of answers are IMO better as a comment. [And](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5012378) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5012380) [regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5012250) [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5012251) for that reason.

…but I was review banned after just [one failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5012389) (which is a very simple answer that could be a comment to a bad question that doesn't deserve even a comment) <sub>*cough mod-ban from declined NAA flag of [similar quality post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933788/using-devise-async-to-send-out-emails-does-not-work-rails-sidekiq/24102546#24102546), declined text includes "please don't waste our time" - not the best attitude cough*</sub>

So what does the community think of answers that just give 30 characters of code with none to very little explanation?

Comment: A thesis by Shog9 on this topic: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)  Those are answers.  They are just not particularly good answers.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it *is an exact answer to the question*. No, it probably shouldn't have been answered. It probably should have been closed to a dupe somewhere. But, it *is* an answer. And this is coming from a guy who **hates** short, code-only, and link-only  answers.

Comment: @jadarnel That was about link-only. I'm also talking about not-even-a-link.

Comment: The exact types of answers you're discussing (including screenshots of them) are at the end of Shog's post.  Whether they have a link or not is irrelevant.  They are answers.

Comment: @jadarnel So what about the other reviewers from the LQP queue that I linked?

Comment: Why are you worried about the other reviewers?

Comment: @jadarnel Because they (not the policy) define what actually gets deleted and kept.

Comment: You probably want to note that most of those answers *haven't* been deleted... There are some sanity-checks to this.

Answer (score 7):

Don't flag answers simply based on their length. Flag them when they don't actually answer the question. The full text of the moderator message you partially quoted already mentioned this. It really is a waste of our time to look at every short answer on the site. (By *our* time I mean everyone looking at the review queues, not just diamond moderators.)

Comment: I don't flag based on length. I said that *in the comments* (that were deleted). I flag based on content, which looked suspiciously like a comment.

Comment: @bjb568 And it looks like a comment because it's short. The review audit you failed is an answer.

Comment: No, it looks like a comment because it has even less information than link-only answers that have been deleted.

Comment: @bjb568 It has enough information to answer the question. That's plenty of *information*. What it lacks is length. Just because something will fit in a comment, doesn't mean it's not an answer.

Comment: Well, if length doesn't matter why is there even a character minimum? Why are most people in the queue reviewing as if it does matter? Why is it that we cannot legally delete crap?

Comment: @bjb568 I don't care about the length of an answer *because there is* a character minimum already in place. If an answer can be posted, judge it on its content, not on its length. It already made it past the character minimum check. We don't need to keep reviewing for that manually.

Comment: Ok, fine. Why does this need a review ban?

Comment: What makes answers so precious anyway? We regularly dump questions away… As the saying goes, there isn't a bad student (VLQ asker), only a bad teacher (VLQ answerer).

Comment: @bjb568 I've never heard that saying, and I don't agree with it. We ban people for asking low quality questions all the time. That's beside the point though, I think. I'll lift your ban, since that's the only review you've failed recently. In the future, please vote to close the question in cases like this, instead of flagging answers.

Comment: Thanks for lifting the ban! The analogy is the student can *always* be helped. But the problem here is that we *aren't* helping because that doesn't scale - i.e. this isn't a help site (tho most people treat it like one then wonder why they're question banned…). Don't worry, I always VTC questions.