# Duplicates of old cobwebbed questions

Tags: discussion

Frequently questions get closed as duplicates.

Often these duplicates are pointed back to questions asked a number of years ago.

Sometimes the information in the answers can be outdated.

What motivation is provided to people who want to provide more up to date information?

When we mark a question as a duplicate of another question that was asked four years ago and already has a star answer with a gazillion upvotes (but presents out of date, albeit correct information in the answers), aren't we misleading the questioner? It's a great way of perpetuating inefficiency... who really scrolls to the end when the top answer "appears" so good?

So why should I bother adding my up-to-date answer that's better (by virtue of added language features, say) when nobody will read it?

Comment: What grace period for new answers?  If you're referring to the ability for a person to finish his answer while his browser is open, after the question gets closed, I don't see what that has to do with this.

Comment: ...to me this problem seems particularly endemic in questions concerning asynchronous IO in C#.

Comment: Prime candidate: a 'reference' answer, accepted with 14 up votes.  Link only.  And the link points to a NuGet node that doesn't exist any more.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859319/json-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're right, I thought it would work for any question, but you need to already have opened the question.

Comment: Unless the question itself is outdated (which would then probably not be an update) I don't see why new information can't be added to the old question as a new answer

Comment: Who reads new answers to questions that have a green check mark and lots of up votes?  Moreover, who votes on them?

Comment: @GayotFow I do. When I read SO Qs to find solutions to my problem I usually read other answers as well. Even more so if one of them starts with "The answer of X is good, but by Date Y this solution is better". And I made the experience that often the newer answers, if well written etc. get sufficient amount of upvotes to make it at least to second place in the list.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer from my experience rarely do really good answers added to old questions float up to the top, even in questions that receive a lot of traffic. This is compounded by the fact that the OP rarely changes the accepted answer even if the new one is much better.

Comment: I have put new answers to old questions and through time they have bubbled to the top. Right now on a few they are the second most upvoted answer. Someone who really wants to solve their problem most effectively will read all the answers. :-)

Comment: I had a question once that was asked over three years ago. I re-asked the question, pointed to the old question and clarified I was looking for updated answer or to know if the old question's answers were still valid. I had my question answered and it was not closed as a duplicate. - I also found a question once that was an old question and I wanted an updated/better answers. I threw a bounty on it and received the answers I was looking for. That is the way I handled this when I run into old questions.

Answer (score 35):

Discussing this in abstract is hard; what you should do depends a lot on the situation.

- You can *always* **add a new answer** that describes new / different solutions to a problem.
- You can *sometimes* **edit existing answers** to correct misinformation or add new methods of doing the same thing.
- You should *sometimes* **flag answers that add nothing** in order to reduce the amount of reading one must do to find alternate solutions.
- You should *occasionally* **ask a new question** if an existing question's answers pertain only to old versions of a given software platform / library / API. If you do this, it's critical that you make it clear how the previous answers and that original question don't reflect the problem you're trying to solve.

But again, which of these make sense in a given situation is going to depend heavily on *that specific situation*.

What you really *never* want to do is to post a question that duplicates an existing question save for the desire to obtain "more up-to-date" answers; first, because there's no guarantee that you will (an awful lot of stuff hasn't changed in 5 years) and second, because even if you *do* folks will still be finding that old question and now won't have the chance to read new answers.

Comment: Example of adding a new answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17177156/2509. It has taken a while to bubble up as some of the existing answers were very highly rated, but it *has* done so. The system works as intended.

Comment: I'm very surprised to learn that an awful lot of stuff hasn't changed in 5 years.

Comment: [Scott Adams taught us that 25 years ago](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4or6U.gif), @Gayot.

Comment: "flag answers that add nothing" [*cough*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259875/2888561)

Comment: Naa is probably a bad choice here, @bjb

Comment: VLQ? They seem to be treated the same.

Comment: `You can always add a new answer that describes new ...` what if the question is protected? Can I still do so?

Comment: If you've contributed *anything else* of value on the site, Protect becomes irrelevant to you @Rahul.

Comment: You mean to say "If my provided answer value adds then I should always post it irrespective of protected" ... right?

Comment: I mean that "Protected" only affects new users, @Rahul. But yes, what you said applies as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick clarification. Do you moderator's have to have a 24hr presence on the site :) [Cause I found that response from a moderator are pretty quick]

Comment: I'm actually not a moderator, @Rahul (check my profile) - but yeah, there are a lot of us around most of the time.

Comment: Also, isn't one of the Bounty options explicitly for getting more up-to-date answers?

Comment: Re "What you really never want to do is to post a question that duplicates an existing question save for the desire to obtain "more up-to-date" answers" - the reasons you give for not doing this are good reasons. Particularly not fragmenting information! But, if I can see that the existing answers are extremely old and suspect the best answer has changed, what then is the right way to request more up-to-date information?

Comment: That depends on *why* you think the answer has changed, @user2428107. See the last bullet: if you know something relevant has changed in a new release, it's fine to ask a new question *about that release*. If you're just asking because the answers are old... Then don't; lots of things simply don't change. Also, be sure to check for new or updated answers to old questions (sort by activity) - you may not *need* a new question if someone's already provided an update to the existing one.

Comment: @Shog9 an awful lot doesn't change in 5 years, but an awful lot does. As a newbie to a fast-changing field, if I can only find answers 5 or more years old and would like to avoid creating a duplicate question, it sounds like the official answer to how I should try to confirm that the info is up-to-date is "don't ask". Respectfully, that leaves newbies like me at a total loss. Surely there is some kind of better channel for asking this minor question ("is this old recommendation still the best option?") than absolute silence. Comments on the original answer, maybe?

Comment: Encouraging folks to re-ask every question every five years isn't a solution either, @user2428107. I'm not saying you can't re-ask *if you have a good reason to think something has changed* - I'm just saying, don't just do so for the hell of it. It should be possible for you to actually *test* any answer worth anything here... So do that. "None of the answers work anymore" is a pretty compelling reason to re-ask.

Comment: @Shog I definitely don't want to be constantly re-asking the question, that's why I posted here. But I also can't necessarily tell whether or not something has changed. I am thinking of questions like "what is a recommended framework or library for task X", where the old solutions probably don't stop working, but nevertheless there's often a newer and better option - under more active development, more supported by the community, etc. I don't know the best way to ask whether there is a newer and better option.

Comment: This is one (of many...) reasons why [such "recommendation" questions are now discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question), @user2428107: they *don't* age well, at all. And, as you note, it's really hard to ever know if they're out of date. So don't ask for a recommendation; ask for a solution to "task X" - if someone ends up finding (or writing) a new library for it, they can still chime in - but you're no longer beholden to whatever is "hot" when you ask.

Answer (score 5):

A clear and necessary starting point is for the OP to have done his homework and **research** the question by himself first.  Google is *not* shy about exposing existing content on SO.  It is the OP's job to point out *in the question* that an existing reference answer is outdated and no longer applies to his problem.

Failure to do this considerably raises the odds that his question gets closed as a duplicate of course.  This is **not** a problem, now he knows and he can either edit his question, ask a new one or put a bounty on the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that new answers to popular old questions can struggle for visibility, and wish that there was some technical solution implemented to combat this (like skewing sorting based upon the *rate* at which answers gain votes instead of just the totals).

Sometimes, [as Shog suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260719/1709587), this means you can more effectively make correct information visible by editing the already accepted or popular answers, or perhaps even asking a new question, than by adding a new answer to a cluttered question.

If you have no reasonable options available to you besides adding a new answer, though, (or somebody else has done so and it's languishing unappreciated), then there are still some promotional tactics you can use to help give it visibility. My unscientific feeling from having used them quite a bit is that they can be effective.

- **Give your answer a tl;dr section at the top**

  If you're adding an answer that is significantly longer and more detailed than the currently accepted or popular ones, ensure that it has an attention-grabbing, easily-digestible summary at the top (separated from the main, lengthy answer using headings) so that impatient people who are skimming over all the answers won't ignore it completely. If you're looking at somebody else's unappreciated answer that is superior but ponderously long, consider editing in such a section.
- **Comment on the obsolete or deficient answers pointing out their flaws, and perhaps linking to the superior answer**

  If the top answer is bad in some way, you want people to keep reading beyond it. You can help achieve that by pointing out the deficiencies of the bad answers in comments. If the comments section is too crowded for your comment to be seen, carefully look through it for obsolete or otherwise worthless comments and flag them - use the moderators to clear the crap out of the way and make your comments more visible. Consider, additionally, linking to superior answers that fix the flaws.
- **Comment on the question itself promoting the superior answer**

  As a matter of etiquette, I would refrain from doing this unless your answer is outright objectively superior to all the existing answers. But sometimes that really is the case, and when it is, making your answer more visible is a proper and useful thing to do.

  The comments section on questions - as long as it's not too cluttered - is highly visible, appearing above even the accepted answer. Exploit this. Post a comment briefly outlining the way in which all the existing answers are flawed and linking to the one true best answer. Again, if the comments section is crowded, consider if you can use moderator flags to eliminate the noise and give your comment greater visibility.
- **Downvote the inferior answers to help the best one overtake them**

  (Only if they're sufficiently bad to deserve it, of course.) It may only be one vote, but every little helps.

Comment: "like skewing sorting based upon the rate at which answers gain votes" < or perhaps introduce time as a weight, e.g. an upvote is only worth 0.5 votes after a year. It might overcomplicate things though, both UI wise and server load wise.