# Closing as duplicate, answers have to "fully" address question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just [closed a question as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417500/python-pandas-convert-string-values-into-rows) which *explicitly said it was a duplicate*, but wanted to double check there wasn't a newer/better answer. This seems reasonable to me (to close as a duplicate) and inline with meta: [Duplicates of old cobwebbed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260718/duplicates-of-old-cobwebbed-questions).

However, the closing message now reads could lead to incorrect behaviour:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not **fully** address your question, **please ask a new question**.

Of course, the OP's question is not *fully* addressed, specifically the part about "newer" solutions. **Fully** seems both lofty and open to interpretation for almost any "different" question...

#### The message suggests they ask a new question asking the same thing, which is not helpful.

*Especially now that my (gold) vote is <strike>binding</strike> immediate, I worry even more whether I am **perceived** to be doing  the correct thing in closing a question...*

Comment: Please see: [Old question, new technology, new answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer)

Comment: @JoshCaswell this is more about the message being ambiguous (the word __fully__).

Comment: @Deduplicator As I say, the message says "fully", I closed it (I stand by that decision) but the message is open to interpretation - suggests OP ought to re-ask question, which of course they shouldn't/

Comment: Gotcha; I misunderstood your emphasis.