# How old does a question have to be to ask it again without having it flagged as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently wanted to ask a question on Stack Overflow and noticed it had already been asked in 2008. Since 7 years have passed and the context of the question has changed dramatically would anyone flag it as a duplicate or is the context of the old question no longer valid?

The question I am referring to if anyone cares is [Find Unused Resources in a .NET Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245956/find-unused-resources-in-a-net-solution)

Comment: I guess it would require a bit of domain knowledge to know for sure, but, specifying the version you're working with might be enough to make it a valid question that will stand on it's own. Might also be helpful to provide a link to the old question and explain why its answers don't answer your question.

Comment: Part of the problem the question itself is rather vague, I assume they were referring to a much older version of Visual Studio but they never mentioned a specific version and people have supplied answers as far back as 2012 for VS 2010 which isn't the current version I am working with, with this it tends to be a very program specific question and not sure if it should even be asked on stackoverflow anymore.

Comment: Right, since it provides no context, no version number, etc, it's rather broad. A question like that would have likely been closed if it were asked today.

Comment: That question sounds like it's shopping for either a solution (aka, do my work for me) or for links to products.  In other words, let sleeping bad questions lie.  In other news, that question doesn't apply to VS 2012, 13,  & 15, which makes a difference in dupe sniffing.

Comment: I have seen a lot of these where they add a note that says "This link looks like a duplicate, but it is not because..." Sometimes it helps to show that you did research on this specific topic and other links that you have tried that did not work.

Comment: Maybe just ask the person who answered the question to update it. There's a discussion about this here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers?cb=1 .

Comment: Well there were multiple answers and finally the answer that was accepted was there ins't a good way to do it.  Which is basically a non answer for me and so much can change in 5 years.

Comment: @James: The accepted answer is a perfectly good explanation of why [**What's being asked for doesn't make sense**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258731/close-reason-for-not-in-my-universe-questions), and you definitely don't want to ask another question that equally makes no sense.  In other similar cases, you'd ask a new question "How do I XYZ in .NET 4.x?" and the question would start by linking "Here's a question discussing .NET 2.0 and here's one for .NET 3.5"

Comment: You may be interested in the discussion of [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817) on Meta.SE.

Comment: ...and this related question I asked some time ago... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260718/duplicates-of-old-cobwebbed-questions

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**N/A**

**The age of a question should not come into account when deciding on duplicates.**

---

Of course, I do not mean that your question is bad or stupid; we all know that technology moves forward and as a result the answers from yesterday might no longer be applicable today or might not be as efficient.

However, age is a poor criterion to differentiate questions on. SO, as a Q&A site, aims at providing answers *immediately*, the edge case where the question is not already answered or cannot be found should be eliminated as much as possible.

In the specific case of old vs new questions, old questions have an inherent advantage in today's search engines (for better or worse), thus if the only difference in the question is the date... it's not worth asking a new question (it might be worth posting a new answer to the existing question, however).

Also, if you have two identical questions, which one should you answer? Both? That's fishy!

It is worth asking a new question if it has novel elements that the old did not: most likely you are prompted to ask a new question because the specifics of the old question do not apply. This means that your situation is different, **you need to characterize this difference** (language/compiler/library versions for example) in the question and maybe with tags.

With the difference characterized, your question is not a duplicate, even if the other one was asked an hour ago.

*Note: as mentioned in the comments, if you ask a newer version of a question, it is worth linking to the older version why a brief of the difference with yours; this way, if anyone stumbles on your question but is more interested by the older version, it's just a click away... and it may prevent your question being closed as duplicate.*

Comment: Well which is better, to edit and try to update an old bad question or just admit the old one is faulty and start a new one.  I had considered both before deciding on the latter.

Comment: @James: Well, that's a different question. If the old question has issues, those should be dealt with regardless of whether you wish to ask a newer form of the question. If it's salvageable, then by all means do so, and then you are in the situation of wanting an updated version; and if it's not salvageable, vote to close... and I found it weird that you want to ask an updated version of something that cannot be salvaged (at first glance) but I guess there are always specific cases.

Comment: Trying to get a good hand on moderation I had seen other questions closed as duplicate for this just I didn't agree with them.  I did flag it to be closed as a bad non answer but I know that review queue is way behind atm.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because I think you are right bottom line age isn't a factor but making sure you are asking something at least significantly different such as version etc,  there were ton of different ways to do different things in different version of angularjs, php or any number of technologies that asking about how to do something with a specific version is valid.

Comment: If you do ask a question, which may seem to be duplicate, it's worth putting the link to the not-so-duplicate question in your own question and briefly explain why those answers do not satisfy you.  At least, it would show that you have tried to find answers first before posting another question.

Comment: @AleksG: Indeed, and it also immediately provides the link for whoever finds your question but is actually in the situation of the "dupe".