# Are optimization questions too specific to be duplicates of similar questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

(This is about a question to which my answer unexpectedly received dozens of upvotes, so you may not consider me an impartial observer.)

Yesterday this question about optimizing the sorting of 10 integers was asked:
[Fastest way to sort 10 numbers? (numbers are 32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172144/fastest-way-to-sort-10-numbers-numbers-are-32-bit)

The question received a few answers and comments, and the discussion included e.g. optimization  by using parallel processing on recent hardware. Then today, the question was marked as a duplicate of this 5-year-old question about sorting 6 integers:
[Fastest sort of fixed length 6 int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786899/fastest-sort-of-fixed-length-6-int-array)

(UPDATE: the duplicate flag seems to have been removed now. I'm still interested in hearing your views on this question in general, though.)

I was wondering whether it makes sense to mark optimization questions as duplicates of related older questions, since what is optimal in one case may not be optimal in another (albeit very similar) case, and also because optimization is closely related to evolution in hardware, and what was optimal 5 years ago, may not be optimal now.

UPDATE: In reaction to some of the comments: I think the problem is that the asker's renewed interest in an old question doens't generate updated answers (unless he sets a bounty). Asking a new question seems to be the best way to say "I have a similar problem, but I'm looking for new answers".

Comment: Is it still marked as duplicate?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova No; apparently that was changed in the last half hour or so. Maybe because of this question, I don't know.

Comment: "what was optimal 5 years ago, may not be optimal now" - so why wouldn't a new answer using newer techniques be a good fit for the old question?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Agreed => [How old does a question have to be to ask it again without having it flagged as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302200/how-old-does-a-question-have-to-be-to-ask-it-again-without-having-it-flagged-as/302260#302260)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Are you suggesting posting answers and comments to the new question on the old question's page? That may make sense if the two questions were identical and only seperated by time, but not when the question is (subtly) different as well.

Comment: I think the problem is that the asker's renewed interest in an old question doens't generate updated answers (unless he sets a bounty). Asking a new question seems to be the best way to say "I have a similar problem, but I'm looking for new answers".

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Ah, indeed there is no easy way to check if a new answers could be brought to an old question without actually creating a duplicate question: if not closed, you get answers, and if closed, you get attention to the older one. That being said, if the answers of the old question are of sufficient quality, they should get you started (fresh new answers on well-known technologies are rare).

Comment: Questions are very similar and answers are essentially identical. Clearly not a duplicate :). Proper way of asking new question would be "for 6 items xxxxx was suggested in _link_here_ and works well for my 10. Are there more specific for 10"...