# How to handle exact duplicate answers (timespan > 2 years)

Tags: discussion, support, specific-answer, plagiarism, duplicate-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36257920/2938364) was posted some minutes ago, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947094/2938364) over two years ago.

The newer answer is (basically) exactly the same, suggesting the exact same code construct.

I found [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable) about the same problem, but there it was mostly a timing-issue (answers posted some seconds appart), which is clearly not the case here.

**Question:**

How should I handle exact duplicate answers? I already added a comment & downvoted. Is there also some flag for exact duplicate answers - I didn't find any?

Comment: No there's no flag for that, except you may raise a user defined flag pointing out obvious plagiarism. Otherwise downvoting and commenting should be sufficient.

Comment: Sometimes a lot happens in two years. Two questions are the same, but the answers will be different because of new insights or advancing technology. How should we handle this?

Comment: @FrankvanWijk: I most probably don't exactly understand what you mean with your comment. The answers I link give the exact same code, they are "the same", no matter advancing technlogies, etc..

Comment: @MarkusWeninger: Sorry I misread your question. You are writing about two same **answers**, what I was wondering was how two handle two same **questions** in a two year timespan. (I probably should have posted this as new question, not as comment. :) )

Comment: @FrankvanWijk: I'm sure your "new" question has already been asked ;)

Comment: @FrankvanWijk: For example, see here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302200/2675154.

Comment: There are a lot of question-questions on meta. Hard to find exactly this situation. This is really becoming meta-meta :) It looks like proper tagging and creating a correct context is the best way to make a question not a duplicate. Edit: thanks for the link, that's a good one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't a specific flag for duplicate answers. You already did the right thing by downvoting. The answer is not useful, as it brings nothing new to the table. That notion can also be expressed in a comment:

> Can you elaborate on how this answer is different from [the same answer posted 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20947094)?

Those with downvote privileges will get the hint.

If the answer is a blatant copy of a previous answer (that is, it appears to have been copied character-by-character) *or* it was obviously "heavily inspired" by a previous answer but does not provide any [attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) to its source of inspiration, then you should flag it for a moderator's attention. Use a custom moderator flag, start your explanation with *Possible plagiarism*, and then explain where it is copied from and if or how attribution is missing.

If I find a single case of plagiarism, I like to sample a few more posts from their profile. Nine out of ten times, they make a habit of it. It is best to do this *before* raising the moderator flag, because then you can include all of that evidence in a single flag, saving the moderators some work and making it more clear what their best course of action would be.

Comment: How would you go about it, when the answer is a duplicate of an answer from a different question? For example with the following word for word duplicate. Answer1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18909619/940834 . Answer2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2318082/940834 . I was going to post a question but felt this one covered most of it

Comment: @Doomsknight that is a blatant copy and is basically plagiarism without proper attribution. Flag the newer answer for moderator attention with the text: *Plagiarism: the answer is an exact copy of [link to other answer] without proper attribution. Not sure if deletion or adding attribution is the correct way foreward*   Your flag will then be handled by a moderator.

Comment: Thanks rene. I have upvoted this answer as its all helped clarify for me.