# How to ask duplicate question that has out-of-date or insufficient past answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

So I recently wanted to try an experiment on SO.  My team and I have recently run up against the dreaded "IE caches AJAX response issue," but IMO, the past iterations of this question have been closed as answered with information that is either out-of-date, too narrow, or doesn't work in many common cases. Obviously I knew that this question was in danger of being flagged as duplicate, but I wanted to try asking it in a way that somehow "made it new again."

Here is the question:

[How to avoid AJAX caching in Internet Explorer 11 when additional query string parameters or using POST are not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261000/how-to-avoid-ajax-caching-in-internet-explorer-11-when-additional-query-string-p)

I completely cop to the fact that simply ruling out past answers in the question itself smells bad.

Whether or not you agree that THIS question is worthy of re-asking, I'm curious how best to handle asking a question that has been answered, and therefore could be tagged as a duplicate, but you feel strongly the past answers are either insufficient or no longer current.

Comment: You can edit the question and put a bounty on it. See [Reasking a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270193/reasking-a-question).

Comment: Is it worth noting, in response to your comment, that I did not ask the original question, and that the original question has an accepted answer with high number of up votes?

Comment: Probably a bit more relevant to the specific situation than what approxiblue linked: [How old does a question have to be to ask it again without having it flagged as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302200/) and especially [Duplicates of old cobwebbed questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260718/)

Comment: @stolli Right, Kendra's example is more similar to your case. Duplicates are duplicates no matter who ask them though.

Answer (score -3):

Based on what I read in the posts linked to in the comments to my question, it seems the best course of action for the OP asking the possible duplicate question is to *clearly articulate the difference and/or reason why the question has become relevant again.*  That's what I did, so I'll let this go at this point.